# adding textviews on the fly

Tags: android

i am currently trying to assign each character that i get from a file in SD card into a different text view

could anyone advise how would i have to do this?

am quite unsure about adding textviews on the fly

```
        try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line="";
        int c,counter=0;
        while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
            line+=(char)c;
            counter++;              
        }
        char[] singleText = line.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 1; i < counter; i++)
        {
            //text.append(singleText[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        //You'll need to add proper error handling here
    }

    //Find the view by its id
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);

    //Set the text
    tv.setText(text);
```

i have done a counter to count how many textviews should be added as well as assigned the characters into an array but i cant seem to find the code to add a textview with a specific size for each char on the fly

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this code ?

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);  
text .setText(questionStatement);  
text .setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(  
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Similarly you can use all of these [lovely api's](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html). To add a text view to your layout you must use `addView()`

Comment: yep this is the code i had added the textview via the xml earlier thus for now i need to use addView() right? if i needed to add any new views